# Laravel CRUD failed Update data to MySQL

Tags: php, html, laravel, crud

I ask for solutions or suggestions regarding my program.

here I try to update the ticket table. however, when I try to debug with json_encode it is empty and there is no change in the update

**RequestActionController**

```php
         public function update(Request $request) { 

            DB::table('ticket')->where('id',$request->id)->update([
                'namacust' => $request->namacust,
                'daerah' => $request->daerah,
                'alamat' => $request->alamat,
                'notlp' => $request->notlp,
                'kategori' => $request->kategori,
                'dpermintaan' => $request->alamat,
                'status' => $request->status
             ]);
              json_encode($request);
          }
```

**route**

```php
    Route::get('main/requestaction/{id}', 'RequestActionController@index');
    Route::post('/ticket/update',         'RequestActionController@update');
```

Comment: Did you list all your routes to ensure that your update route works? Also, how are you using that route? In a blade? Wheres that code

Comment: Try this `dd($request->all();)` instead of `json_encode($request);` you will know the data is coming or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the request data by two ways.

```php
dd($request->all());
```

OR

```php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($request->all());
die;
```

Comment: thank you, it helps me even more.

but the data from the view is still not entered. is there an error in my update function

Comment: @DyanBent please check $request->id is coming in request data or not